# Async loop in sequence

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to ask why this async loop works, but when i change it to use function as parameter it just prints out 1 testing and then just jumps at the end like nothing happens. Any Idea ? Is it cause function can be used just once or ?. Or do you have a better way how to do a async loop in sequence ?

```
let array=[10,9,7,6,5,4];
fnBlockLoop(array)

    function timeoutTest(delay){
      return new Promise((resolve)=>{
        console.log("testing")
        setTimeout(resolve,delay)
      })
    }

    async function fnBlockLoop(input,func){
        for(const item of input){
            let test = await timeoutTest(2000);
            console.log(test)
        }
        console.log("done")
    }
```

2

```
    let array=[10,9,7,6,5,4];
    fnBlockLoop(array,timeoutTest(2000))


function timeoutTest(delay){
  return new Promise((resolve)=>{
    console.log("testing")
    setTimeout(resolve,delay)
  })
}

async function fnBlockLoop(input,func){
    for(const item of input){
        let test = await func;
        console.log(test)
    }
    console.log("done")
}
```

Comment: In the second example, you do not pass the function, but its results as a parameter. Hence, there is nothing to wait for in the loop and it will just proceed.

Comment: I see hm, Can I somehow pass function as parameter ?

Comment: @trixo: You pass a function by _passing the function_ rather than calling it. So instead of `fnBlockLoop(array,timeoutTest(2000))`, do `fnBlockLoop(array,timeoutTest)`

Comment: `fnBlockLoop(array, async function(){ timeoutTest(2000) } )` or `fnBlockLoop(array, timeoutTest, 2000 )`. 2nd variant needs some adaptations within the function body of `fnBlockLoop()`

Comment: @Sirko Write answer I ll accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want, is to pass the function reference `timeoutTest` along. What you currently do, is to pass the result of a function call `timeoutTest( 2000 )` along. The later is a `Promise`, which can only resolve once.

To pass the actual function reference along you have to options:

1. Add an anonymous function wrapper. This will let you use other functions as input: `fnBlockLoop(array, async function(){ await timeoutTest(2000) } )`
2. Pass the function reference and its parameters. This needs some adjustments in your `fnBlockLoop()` function: `fnBlockLoop(array, timeoutTest, 2000 )`

Comment: I feel like first option does not work tho :) but second does

Comment: @trixo Change `let test = await func;` to `let test = await func();` and it should work also. Here you did the same error the other way around: using the reference instead of a call.

Comment: hm cant make it run Have no idea where s problem :) Could you try to recreate first option in fiddle ? :)

Comment: @trixo My Bad. Forgot a keyword myself. Adding that `await` makes it work. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v0rvhLr7/).

Answer (score 0):

> You should be passing the function reference like this.

```
   let array=[10,9,7,6,5,4];
    fnBlockLoop(array,timeoutTest)


function timeoutTest(delay){
  return new Promise((resolve)=>{
    console.log("testing")
    setTimeout(resolve,delay)
  })
}

async function fnBlockLoop(input,func){
    for(const item of input){
        let test = await func(2000);
        console.log(test)
    }
    console.log("done")
}
```